# Neo4j modelling - sorting nodes ordered by distance

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am using Neo4j with PHP.
In my project, I have restaurant nodes. Each node has latitude, longitude and taxonomy properties.

I need to return the restaurant nodes matching user's given taxonomy with results ordered by distance from user's location (that is nearest restaurant at the first).

What is the easiest solution?

I have worked on Mongo DB and Elasticsearch,this is very easy to achieve there using special indexing. But I could not find a straightforward way in Neo4j.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of solutions :

- Using neo4j spatial plugin : https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/spatial
- Computing the distance yourself with `haversin` in Cypher : http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-functions-mathematical.html#functions-spherical-distance-using-the-haversin-function
- In 3.0Mx there should be basic Cypher functions for point and distance : https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/pull/5397/files (I didn't tested it though)

Answer (score 2):

Besides the aforementioned Neo4j-Spatial, in Neo4j 3.0 there is also a built in `distance()` function.

See this GraphGist:

http://jexp.github.io/graphgist/idx?dropbox-14493611%2Fcypher_spatial.adoc

So if you find and match your restaurants some way you can order them by distance:

```
MATCH (a:Location), (b:Restaurant)
WHERE ... filtering  ...
RETURN b
ORDER BY distance(point(a),point(b))
```

Comment: Thanks for the gist link !

Answer (score 1):

[Neo4j Spatial](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/spatial) features distance queries (among lots of other things) and also cares about ordering.

Comment: Max de Marzi also has a nice blog post on how you can use Neo4j Spatial for recommendations, including distance: http://maxdemarzi.com/2014/02/11/neo4j-spatial-part-2/